# selecting specific integer from list

Tags: python

I want to be able to pull the largest odd integer from a list. So far I have been able to create a list based on user input but I can't quite figure out the coding used to pull the largest odd integer.

Here is what I have so far

```
numberlist=[]
for iteration in range(10):
    number = int(raw_input('Give an integer'))
    numberlist.append(number)
print max(numberlist)
```

Additional Info:
Using Pythong 2.7

Answer (score 3):

You could do this most easily with a generator comprehension.

```
max(x for x in numberlist if x&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use list comprehensions to iterate the list and only keep the odd ones when calling max():

```
numberlist=[]
for iteration in range(10):
    number = int(raw_input('Give an integer'))
    numberlist.append(number)
print max(n for n in numberlist if n & 1)
```

Comment: Technically, that's a generator comprehension. You need to add brackets to get a list.

Comment: That worked really well, thank you. I'll have to read up on list comprehensions as I have no idea what that one line works

Comment: @Antimony - Yeah, it is a generator expression - I used the term 'list comprehension' because that's covered extensively in the python tutorial.

Comment: @Jose Rodriguez it's definately worth reading up on. Try "print [n for n in numberlist if n & 1]" and you will see a list of odd numbers. It works pretty much as you would say it: give me all the n's in numberlist if n is odd".

Comment: how does the program know I am interested in the odd number? Does the "1" in the line print max(n for n in numberlist if n & 1) signify odd? Is there a source I can read to find out what other numbers might signifiy? For example, does using a 2 mean even? What bout 3, 4,5..etc?

Comment: @Jose Rodriguez - good question. I used `n & 1` because I know that in binary, all odd numbers have their lowest bit set. This only works for binary aligned numbers 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and etc... In general, you can use modulo operations (%) to see if an integer is evenly divided by some number. Even numbers are divisible by 2, so `n % 2 == 0` tests for even numbers and `n % 2 != 0` tests for odd numbers. In general, for some number x `n % x == 0` tells you whether n is divisible by x.

Comment: What if a user puts no odd integers. Would adding the following line yeild the desired result?
    if n for n in numberlist %2 == 0
        print 'No odd integers'

Comment: @JoseRodriguez - Good question! In the original answer, max() throws a ValueError exception if there are no odd integers. You would wrap it in a try/except block to give good feedback to the user. The example you give isn't quite right... you need a list and you need to look for odd numbers `if len([n for n in numberlist if n % 2 != 0]) == 0: print 'no odd integers'`. That could be sped up with a for loop that breaks when it sees the first odd integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to grab the odds from your list in the `max` function.

```
print max(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, numberlist))
```

The lambda function is used by the filter to grab only odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

prob not the most efficient, but..

```
numberlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,23,17,19]
numerList = filter(lambda x: x %2 > 0, numberlist);
print max(numerList)
```